# string placeholder and regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, silverlight

I have created a method where I can search for string placeholders, this I do with Regular expressions.
At the moment I try to expand this method by adding grouping features.

For example if I have this string:

```
"Hallo {g:test1} asdasd {p:test1} sdfsdf{o:test1}"
```

I want to :

1. Search for the string test1, even if there is standing a letter:(like g:) before it.
2. I want to search for: all strings with for example a g: before it.

I can't really figure out how to do this in C# can someone help me?

At the moment I programmed this:

```
private string test() {
      string pattern = @"\{(.*?)\}";
      string query = "Hallo {g:test1} asdasd {p:test1} sdfsdf{o:test1}";

      var matches = Regex.Matches(query, pattern);

      foreach (Match m in matches) {
        Test = m.Groups[1].Value;
      }

      return Test;
    }
```

Comment: The regex looks ok - what's the problem?

Comment: This regex searches for strings inside brackets, that works. But now i want to find for example test1 string inside the brackets even if g: stands before it, because now I get this error with n-unit:
Expected: "test1"
  But was:  "o:test1"

And i want also a function so that i can find all string with (for example) g: before it, so in this case it must result test1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 \{(?:.:)?(.*?)\}
```

It will match the text not including the letter and the colon which may be before it.

To limit this to strings with a particular letter before it:

```
 \{(?:#:)(.*?)\}   replacing # with the letter you are filtering on
```

e.g.

```
 \{(?:g:)(.*?)\}
```

Comment: ok this is correct.
But now step two, what if I want to only search for the strings with g: before it or o:, or any letter: before it.

Comment: There is only one problem with the last solution. If I have for example:  string query = "Hallo {g:test2} aaaa {g:test3} asdasd {p:test1} sdfsdf{o:test1}";
Then it only selects test3 and it needs to select test2 and select3, do i need to put them in a array?

Comment: it selects both test2 and test3 - m.Groups[0].Value and m.Groups[1].Value

Answer (score 0):

1. `\{.:test1\}`
2. `\{g:.+?\}`